# Why can't I use <experimental/barrier>?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to use `std::experimental::barrier` in my  cpp multi-threaded code. But even if I write a code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <experimental/barrier>

int main () {

  return 0;
}
```

the compiler throws an error saying that:

```
experimental/barrier: No such file or directory
 #include <experimental/barrier>
                               ^`
```

I am using g++ version 6.3.0 on my Ubuntu machine.
This is the command I am trying:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 top.cpp -o top_new
```

Comment: Because your compiler does not support it

Comment: you need late version of gcc, greater than 6.0.  File System TS is experimental at best. stable blends in Ubuntu do not support it

Comment: I can't get it to run with GCC 7.2 on Wandbox either. (https://wandbox.org/permlink/JgDT3DBH6CvNvZXo)

Comment: @Arnav Borborahfor now experimentals are available only development branches. Which you supposed to download and build yourself

Comment: @Swift Ah, I see. I was confused by what you said with GCC 6.0

Comment: Per [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) it doesn't look like it comes standard

Answer (score -2):

Currently this library is not yet available.

Maybe this will be usefull:
[The GNU C++ Library Manual -> Part III.  Extensions -> 30. Concurrency](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/ext_concurrency.html)

> The file <ext/concurrence.h> contains all the higher-level constructs for playing with threads. In contrast to the atomics layer, the concurrence layer consists largely of types. All types are defined within namespace __gnu_cxx.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, there are two macros
>
> _GLIBCXX_READ_MEM_BARRIER
>
> _GLIBCXX_WRITE_MEM_BARRIER
>
> Which expand to the appropriate write and read barrier required by the host hardware and operating system.